# How to formulate a function for Django Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to run a function in tasks.py(or celery.py) that sends email. The arguments "msg" and "email" will differ from one schedule to another.
In the CrontabSchedule djcelery database table, I have several cron schedules example:

> CrontabSchedule: 0 4 * * *

This cron is also linked to a task in PeriodicTask djcelery database tables . example:

> PeriodicTask: celery.send_email

PeriodicTask and CrontabSchedule can be accessed by doing.

> from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, CrontabSchedule

The 3 models are linked through CrontabSchedule.id ---> PeriodicTask.crontab_id ---> Schedule.crontab_id

myapp.models.Schedule is defined by me while theother 2 came from djcelery.

Now, when celery goes into this cron schedules to run job task, how does the task SendEmail function will be able to know which "Schedule.message" and "Schedule.email" to use from the database table entry for the SendEmail function arguments "msg" and "email" respectively. This is a case of one task name many CrontabSchedule, PeriodicTask, Schedule entries. I will appreciate a skeleton(sample code) SendEmail function.

Please help. I hope I explained it well cause its turning my head.

tasks.py

```
@task
def SendEmail(msg, email):
```

model.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    email = models.OneToOneField(MyCustomUser, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Example')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=918)
    startdatetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, default=datetime.now)
    recurrences = RecurrenceField()
    crontab_id = models.CharField(max_length=999999, unique=True)
```

Django Celery models tables

### CrontabSchedule

```
-id
-minute
-hour
-day_of_week
-day_of_month
-month_of_year
```

### PeriodicTask

```
-id
-name
-task
-args
-kwargs
-queue
-exchange
-routing_key
-expires
-enabled
-last_run_at
-total_run_count
-date_changed
-description
-crontab_id
-interval_id
```

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly you need help with here. Have you looked at the existing package _django-celery-beat_? Maybe you can use that instead of creating your own django app for managing scheduled tasks? https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat

Comment: Yes, django-celery-beat, I have gone through the documentation. It sort of similar to djcelery. But my requirement is requires that when celery kicks off the job task, the SendEmail function task must pick up a corresponding "message" & "email" from the Schedule database table.